# toolbar overlaps my fragments (multi pane)

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to have two fragments shown at the same time on a horizontal orientation of my activity alongwith a toolbar. But the toolbar overlaps the fragments. I'm not sure where to place it. Btw, the toolbar comes with a navigation view, so it's in a drawerlayout.

Here's my xml.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content_fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_app_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/activity_fragment_main_event_list"
            class="com.torneyo.torneyoadmin.fragments.EventListFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/activity_fragment_main_event_detail"
            class="com.torneyo.torneyoadmin.fragments.EventDetailFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thoughts? I need to have the fragments show up. I'm not sure I'm using the layouts correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I see your layout file. I think the problem in it. It should inside the relative layout. kindly see the below modified layout version. Apply it let me know if you have any question in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_app_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content_fragments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_app_toolbar"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/activity_fragment_main_event_list"
                class="com.torneyo.torneyoadmin.fragments.EventListFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/activity_fragment_main_event_detail"
                class="com.torneyo.torneyoadmin.fragments.EventDetailFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```